# How to get specific attributes from all xml files in directory?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a folder full of xml files. In these files many of them share a common attribute (Name), but have a secondary attribute that is different. I want to get a list of the unique entries based off reading these xml files. Below is an example of what the various xml files will contain.

**File 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results date="2013-12-29">
<A uniqueId="1234" Name="My-Machine"/>
<error number="555">
<description><![CDATA[House on Fire]]></description>
</error>
</results>
```

**File 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results date="2013-12-29">
<A uniqueId="1234" Name="My-Machine"/>
<error number="556">
<description><![CDATA[House in flood]]></description>
</error>
</results>
```

**File 3**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results date="2013-12-29">
<A uniqueId="1234" Name="My-Machine"/>
<error number="556">
<description><![CDATA[House in flood]]></description>
</error>
</results>
```

I need to be able to read all the files, add each Name and description to a list (or possibly array). Output from example would look like this:

```
Name="MyMachine", description="![CDATA[House is flooding]]";    
Name="MyMachine", description="![CDATA[House on fire]]";    
Name="MyMachine", description="![CDATA[House on fire]]";
```

It seems LINQ may be the best way to handle this since the files are very small in content.

Comment: LINQ is convenient, but it's not recommendable if you expect these files to be big. LINQ parses the entire xml file at once. You can use `XmlReader` instead to read them sequentially... To me, you are asking at least two different questions at once right now: how to read the files in, and how to process their contents. The answer to the latter depends on the former.

Comment: The files will not be big (the example is roughly the size of the actual files) except that there may be thousands of xml files. Would LINQ then be ill advised due to this? I might be asking multiple questions at once, if for no other reason than I don't know enough about reading xml to ask it simply enough.

Comment: LINQ will be fine here. Your question is definitely asking a lot. I might post up an answer with pieces of a complete solution but I probably won't write the whole thing. You need to iterate over every file in the dir reading them one by one and adding all the name-description pairs to a list. After that you can use LINQ's group by function to group by name (and produce counts).

Comment: Are those three nodes a full file? Shouldn't there be some root element enclosing that list of items? Also the description is not a property or child element of `A` which contains the name... That will make parsing the file more difficult/less consistent.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a suitable built in functionality of one of the XML reading options that would simplify this. It sounds like probably not. I have updated the question to just ask how to use LINQ to get the information into a list.

Comment: The example you posted is not valid xml, is it the actual file content?

Comment: I added the parts that I thought would be necessary to parsing the xml file. I have updated the question with the full contents.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to read that `description` element content from one file:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");
var name = "My-Machine";

var aElement = xDoc.Root.Element("A");

string description = null;
if ((string)aElement.Attribute("Name") == name)
    description = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("error").Element("description");
```

It will return the element value when `Name` attribute value matches your `name` variable. Otherwise `description` will be `null`.